# iisnode does not store cookie in Chrome

Tags: node.js, iis, iisnode

I have an nodejs/expressjs Web API project setup that works perfectly fine when I test locally. But when I test by making a request to the API hosted in IIS, Google Chrome doesn't save the cookie. Otherwise with Firefox, where I make a request to log in, but it does not save the cookie, however I can request resources protected by authentication. With Postman, I have no problem.

```
   <system.webServer>
   <handlers>  
      <add name="iisnode" path="app.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode" />  
    </handlers>  
     <rewrite>
       <rules>
         <rule name="api">
           <match url="api/*" />
           <action type="Rewrite" url="app.js" />
         </rule>
       </rules>
     </rewrite>
     <iisnode 
       enableXFF="true"
       nodeProcessCommandLine="&quot;%programfiles%\nodejs\node.exe&quot;"  
       interceptor="&quot;%programfiles%\iisnode\interceptor.js&quot;" />
    <httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough" />
   </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

This is the app.js

```
app.set('trust proxy', 1)
app.use(
    cors({
        credentials: true,
        origin: true
    })
);
app.use(morgan('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
mongoose.connect(keys.mongodb.dbURI, { useNewUrlParser: true });

app.use(session({
    proxy: true,
    secret: keys.session.cookieKey,
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    cookie: { maxAge: 1 * 60000, httpOnly: false },
    store: new MongoStore({
        mongooseConnection: mongoose.connection
    })
}));
```

This is a portion of code making a post request to iisnode

```
      axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;
      axios
        .post("http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx//api/login", {
          email: this.email,
          password: this.password,
          withCredentials: true
      })
   .then(response => {
```

Comment: Have you seen IIS send cookie to browser? There is no cookie configuration for web browser in IISnode. If you can see that cookie in fiddler. It would probably be an browser side security issue.

Comment: yes there is the Set-Cookie header in the response but it is not saved in the browser